# Persistent problems connecting MySQL Workbench to an AWS RDS DB

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, mysql-workbench, aws, connections

I started off my attempt to figure out how to connect my local MySQL Workbench (8.0.32) client/application to an RDS Database on my analytics team's AWS Account by asking Bing AI and this is what it gave me: "In the Setup New Connection dialog box, enter a name for your connection. In the Parameters section, enter these details: Hostname: The endpoint for your DB instance. Port: The port number for your DB instance (default is 3306). Username: The name of the master user for your DB instance. Password: The password for the master user. Click Test Connection to ensure the connection is configured properly and click OK."

So, I went and found the Endpoints, but there are two of them for this RDS Database, one for read operations and another for write, so I tried it copying+pasting each of them in the Hostname spot, and I ended up getting the same alternating three outcomes when using both of them.
The 1st outcome is that MySQL Workbench freezes and says (Not Responding) in the top bar for a while, nothing happens, then I can use it again.

2nd outcome:
[image]

3rd outcome:
[image]